# What are some engines for general-purpose finite automata?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, rule-engine, finite-automata, fsm

The requirements are:

- basic automat functions: states, events, rules
- flexibility (integration with external language tools for analysis, classification, search)
- declaratives, changes without recompilation
- [optional] randomization capabilities (e.g. for randomized transition between states)

e.g. similar to [Akka FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html), but with declarative capabilities. Flexible rule-based and text matching (based on NLP) is helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of libraries which can handle [UML state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) --- would that work for you?

- [The Boost Statechart Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/statechart/doc/rationale.html)
- [The North State Framework™](http://www.northstatesoftware.com/uml-state-machine-code-generation-framework.html)
- [The Quantum Platform](http://www.state-machine.com/products/index.html#QP)
- [SinelaboreRT](http://www.sinelabore.com/)

Comment: @NikitaZhiltsov: If this answer helped you out, I'd be very grateful if you could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it as I'm currently trawling for a few extra reputation points; Thanks a lot for the help.